# How can I configure by CodeBuild to not trigger CodePipeline recursively

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

Currently my CodeBuild is cloning the source CodeCommit Repository, making some changes on it and pushing it to the origin, this causes the pipeline to be triggered recursively since the source code is changing every time.  I want to stop the pipeline trigger after pushing the changes to the Source Repository

Answer (score 0):

Two quick and simple solutions:

1. The simplest solution is to disable your Pipeline and enable it when you want to it to work again.
2. Or depends on which branch your Pipeline tracks, assuming it is the main/master branch. A better practice is to do your development in a different git branch. Then merge that branch to your main/master branch to trigger the Pipeline.